# Knockout bind input text box to another text box

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I have two input tags and I want the exact same value to be in both when I type in one.
I am experimenting with knockout and am wondering how I would accomplish this.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: theValue" />
<br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: theValue" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
    theValue: ko.observable("defaultText"),
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct, you just want to add `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` to your bindings so they update as you type.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: theValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: theValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Also, `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());` should be `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`

Here's a [**full demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/16197/)